# Intellij class path setting when build a jar for maven project

Tags: classpath, intellij-13

when running the jar in command line, throw this exception:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
When building jar in intellij, we need set the manifest properties, like main class, class path, where could I find the right setting for this? it is not in the manifest file

Comment: May be you are looking for POM.xml, here is an article that gives more details about this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19245271/questions-to-intellijidea-and-maven

Comment: thanks, already solved