# Include FontAwesomeFX Icons and Glyphs from FXML

Tags: java, javafx, font-awesome

---

1. **Sector 1** (The great [FontAwesomeFX](https://bitbucket.org/Jerady/fontawesomefx))

---

- Mention that the `JFXBadge` is coming from the [JFoenix](http://jfoenix.com/) Library,
  I found the code downloading their demo from [github](https://github.com/jfoenixadmin/JFoenix/tree/master/demo).

Back in the old time of `FontAwesomeFX 8.5.0`< i could include in the app icons using:

```
<?import de.jensd.fx.fontawesome.Icon?>
<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXBadge?>

<HBox spacing="20" style="-fx-padding: 0 0 0 50;">
                <children>
 <JFXBadge fx:id="badge1" styleClass="icons-badge" text="1">
     <Icon awesomeIcon="STAR" size="2em" style=";" styleClass="icon" />
  </JFXBadge>               
     </children>
</HBox>
```

---

**Old solution:**

The line you needed was:

```
<Icon awesomeIcon="STAR" size="2em" style=";" styleClass="icon" />
```

---

Now after several updates i added the [newest jar](https://bitbucket.org/Jerady/fontawesomefx) (`8.9`) but i have no clue how to do this?

**In plain java** code you can do it using the answer from [FontAwesomeFX - only rectangles displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31271800/fontawesomefx-only-rectangles-displayed)

---

**Finally:**

How can i include icons from `FontAwesomeFX` to the `.fxml` like above so i can live check them through `SceneBuilder` and i have not to do compile run dance.

Answers including `ControlsFX` will be also accepted :) , i need to include the icons either in one way or another.

---

An icon from the version `8.0.10`:

[image]

An icon from the version `8.9.0` (Everything is different):

[image]

---

2. **Sector 2** (The great [ControlsFX](http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/features/))

---

A [discussion](http://(https://bitbucket.org/controlsfx/controlsfx/pull-requests/381/basic-refactoring-of-glyph-font-system-306/diff)) for the code below from `BitBucket`.

It is `6:45 am` I am trying with `ControlsFX 8.40` and nothing works ..... :( omggggggggg :

```
<?import org.controlsfx.glyphfont.*?>
//...
<Label>
    <graphic>
        <Glyph fontFamily="FontAwesome" icon="PLUS" />
    </graphic>
</Label>
//...
```

I am getting a rectangle from the code above ...

Comment: Hi. Have you managed to use FontAwesomrFX from fxml?

Comment: @rvit34 I wanted to achieve the below answer , i used the old FontAwesome. It worked so i left it as is . But i am open to any recommendations . I don't think that JFXBadge supports the newest version of Font Awesome .

Comment: Why did you not use `FontAwesomeIconView` instead of old `Icon`?

Comment: @rvit34 Can you provide an answer on it and how to add it on JFXBadge ?

Comment: Try `<FontAwesomeIconView glyphName="STAR" glyphSize="your size"  styleClass="icon"/>`

Comment: @rvit34 Thanks i will test it ☺.

Answer (score 1):

I am adding this answer until someone answer the question.

---

**I want to create the below** which is a `JFXBadge`:

[image]

The old code i use(with `FontAwesomeFX 8.0.10`):

**FXML** Part:

```
<?import de.jensd.fx.fontawesome.Icon?>
<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXBadge?>

//..
<HBox spacing="20" style="-fx-padding: 0 0 0 50;">
                <children>
 <JFXBadge fx:id="badge1" styleClass="icons-badge" text="1">
     <Icon awesomeIcon="STAR" size="2em" style=";" styleClass="icon" />
  </JFXBadge>               
     </children>
</HBox>
//..
```

**CSS** part for the text(`Top-RIGHT`) and the actual `ICON`:

```
.icon{
    -fx-text-fill: #FE774D;
    -fx-padding: 10.0;
    -fx-cursor: hand;
}

.icons-badge .badge-pane {
    -fx-background-color:#ff4081;
    -fx-background-radius:23.0; 
    -fx-pref-width: 23.0;
    -fx-pref-height: 23.0;  
    -fx-alignment: center;
}

.icons-badge Label{
    -fx-font-weight: BOLD;
    -fx-font-size: 13.0px !important;
    -fx-text-fill: WHITE;
}
```