# Use last version of fontawesomefx in SceneBuilder

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

Previously, when import jar file in Scene Builder, I get `FontAwesomeIconView`, `WeatherIconView` (for example when import `fontawesomefx-8.5.jar`).

Now, when I import `fontawesomefx-commons-8.13.jar`, I get only `GlyphStack`; for `fontawesomefx-controls-8.13.jar` - only `GlyphCheckBox`. No icon components.

There are now some ability to work with an icon visually in Scene Builder as before?

Comment: This <<may>> help someway http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41094114/inlcude-fontawesomefx-icons-and-glyphs-from-fxml

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
I solved this problem by importing these three libraries instead of importing fontawesomefx-8.9.jar (which was the latest version when I was importing ):

[image: libraries]

[image: fonticonviewimport]

Hope this helps!

Comment: where did you find these jar-files? I am searching at mvncentral and the latest fontawesomefx-commons-jar is 8.11. Would be great if you could give me a hint

Answer (score -1):

You may import the special icon packages, for example:

```
de.jensd:fontawesomefx-fontawesome:4.7.0
de.jensd:fontawesomefx-materialicons:2.2.0-1
```

Those packages have a IconView in them.

[image]

Comment: I try load these jar in Scene Builder, but not see anything components in Import dialog..