# How to add .so and .h iles in one jar using maven?

Tags: java, file, maven

I have a project with JNI libraries inside it not in resources folder. I need to create one exetutable jar file.
How to teach maven copy needed files inside jar and put in needed folders?

Please explain how to add my files from lib directory near my project to a jar file using maven. Or how to copy my files and directories to jar using maven?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a runnable jar with maven that includes dependencies in a separate "lib" folder (not an uber jar)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9244738/how-to-create-a-runnable-jar-with-maven-that-includes-dependencies-in-a-separate)

Comment: This question has already been answered multiple times. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229757/maven-add-a-dependency-to-a-jar-by-relative-path?rq=1